# Enabling the past function

Tags: fine-uploader

Reading the docs it mentions "also containing the file list" in the paste options for the target element 
http://docs.fineuploader.com/integrating/options/fineuploaderbasic.html

What is this? Is there a good example how to implement this? This is what I have so far. #pasteimage is a text box.

Using Chrome 10.6  Do I need to turn it on somewhere in jquery.fineuploader-3.4.1.js

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
                var thumbnailuploader = new qq.FineUploader({
                    element: $('#thumbnail-fine-uploader')[0],
                    request: {
                        endpoint: '/Admin/CFC/image-uploader.cfc?method=Upload',
                        params: {
                           profileID: '<cfoutput>#profile.ID#</cfoutput>',
                           profileType:'<cfoutput>#profile.Profile_Type#</cfoutput>',
                           subDName:'<cfoutput>#DecodeforHTML(profile.Subdomain_Name)#</cfoutput>'
                                },

                    },
                    multiple: true,
                    validation: {
                        allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png'],
                        sizeLimit: 102400, // 100 kB = 100 * 1024 bytes
                        itemLimit: 1,
                        stopOnFirstInvalidFile: false
                    },
                    text: {
                        uploadButton: "\+ Click or Drop"
                    },
                    paste:{
                            targetElement:$('#pasteimage')
                           },

                    callbacks: {
                        onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON){
                            if (responseJSON.success) {
                                $('#thumbnail-fine-uploader').append('<img src="/<cfoutput>#profile.Profile_Type#</cfoutput>/<cfoutput>#profile.ID#</cfoutput>/' + responseJSON.filename + '" alt="' + fileName + '" style="width:120px;height:120px;">');
                                $('#thumbnail-fine-uploader').append('<br/><b style="color:red;">' + responseJSON.returnedProfileID + '<br/>'+ responseJSON.returnedprofileType+'<br/>'+responseJSON.returnedsubDName+'</b>');
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    onUpload: function(id, fileName){
                        $('#file-' + id).addClass('alert-info').html('<img src="/Images/loading.gif" alt="Initializing. Please hold."> ' +
                        'Initializing ' +
                        '“' +
                        fileName +
                        '”');
                    },
                    onProgress: function(id, fileName, loaded, total){
                        if (loaded < total) {
                            progress = Math.round(loaded / total * 100) + '% of ' + Math.round(total / 1024) + ' kB';
                            $('#file-' + id).removeClass('alert-info').html('<img src="/Images/loading.gif" alt="In progress. Please hold."> ' +
                            'Uploading ' +
                            '“' +
                            fileName +
                            '” ' +
                            progress);
                        }
                        else {
                            $('#file-' + id).addClass('alert-info').html('<img src="/Images/loading.gif" alt="Saving. Please hold."> ' +
                            'Saving ' +
                            '“' +
                            fileName +
                            '”');
                        }
                    },
                })
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paste target element can be any container that will receive the pasted image(s).  This is where your users will paste any image on their clipboard.  There isn't much to demonstrate.  Simply create an element in the DOM, preferably one that your users can understand is the location where images can be pasted.  Then, set this element as the value of the `paste` option's `targetElement` property.  You can even use the `document` as a target, if you want.

Comment: Not sure what I'm doing wrong them. I have edited my original post

Comment: You are using chrome 10.6? Is that a typo?  If you really are using a version of chrome that old, the paste feature will not work.

Comment: Also you are passing a jquery object as a value for targetElement.  You must pass an htmlelement, unless you are using the jquery plugin, which you are not.

Comment: Ray yes correction Chrome Version 26.0.1410.65.  Sorry I'm very new at this stuff. Can you give me a hint to pass an htmlelement?

Comment: Ok well any thoughts to why its not working? Image is copying. But when I paste into text box nothing.  Click or Drag/Drop is working fine.

Comment: Have you fixed the targetElement as I mentioned?

Comment: Not really clear on what you mean. I have 
paste:{        targetElement:$('#pasteimage')
},

<div ID='pasteimage' style='width:150px;height:150;border:solid thin white'></div>

Comment: Your targetElement MUST be an Element/Node, NOT a jQuery object.  Just like the value of the `element` option, which you have correctly set.  So, your targetElement value must be `$('#pasteImage')[0]`.